# Process mysql function and display using jquery ajax (with time invterval for each)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

LOL idk if the title correct, but let me explain

Hi.. Iam newbie on jquery ajax and have some problem here

right now i have db called url.sql with this format

```
tbl_url
---------------------------------------------------- 
+   url_id    +  url_link                        +
----------------------------------------------------
+      1      + http://somelink.com/page/2/      +
----------------------------------------------------
+      2      + http://somelink.com/page/3/      +
----------------------------------------------------
```

also have php code called run.php like this one

```
<?php
$h = "localhost";
$u = "root";
$p = "root";
$d = "url";

$c = mysql_connect("$h","$u","$p");

if (!$c) die ("Fail");

mysql_select_db($d,$c) or die ("db cant find"); 

    $url_query=mysql_query('select * from url');

        include('simple_html_dom.php');

        $html = new simple_html_dom(); 

        while($url_row=mysql_fetch_row($url_query)) {

            $eachpage=$urlpost_row['url_link'];

            $html = file_get_html($eachpage);

            foreach($html->find(".class h2") as $eachtitle){

                $eachtitle = $eachtitle->plaintext;

                echo $eachtitle."<br/>";

                $submit_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_url(url_link) VALUES('$eachtitle')");

            }

        }

    ?>
```

and then html file called form.html

```
<input type="button" id="display" value="Process All Data" /> 

<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">

</div>
```

My question is how to do an jquery-ajax to process the run.php

I mean i want its look like this:

When i click button on form.html, the run.php will work with 5 second delay for each row, i ask this using jquery-ajax because the url.sql have lot of rows, to avoid timeout on php i prefer using ajax rather than set_time_limit

i really blank / zero about jquery-ajax

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the below code on onclick

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    jQuery.ajax({
                url:'YOUR PHP url',
                type:'POST',
                data:'SEND YOUR DATA',
                success:function(results){
                    jQuery("#oresponsecontainer").html(results);

                }
            });
```

Comment: url:run.php, but on data: what should i fill? also how to set interval for each process..? i mean from row 1 to row 2 it need about 2 - 5 second before continue

Comment: on data, fill what you wanto to send on run.php file. Else remove that part.

Comment: you want to show all data rows together or one by one ?

Comment: i want to run all data, but with delay every 5 second, so like data1 show(delay5second)data2 show above data1(delay5second)data3 show above data2(delay5second) and so on.. till end, and at the end, will give info, maybe like "all process done" btw still dont understand with the DATA: part