# Get posts from all categories except one category

Tags: mysql

**While searching, I want all posts from all categories except one category**

**This is my search query**

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title like '%$search%' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC`

In this query, i don't want **book** category posts. when i search any keyword, need to display all posts except **book** category posts

**Any help?**

Comment: I tried this code. it's not working.
`SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_title like '%$search%'
AND category != 'book'
AND post_type =  'post'
AND post_status =  'publish'
ORDER BY post_date DESC`

Comment: Sorry. i dono, where i get the category name.In wp_posts have full of post details.can u help me.

Comment: I found the category name in my table. <b>name</b> is my category name. i tried name != 'book'.not working

Comment: i checked the category name in my table, same like 'name'.</br> In wp_terms table, category name column is here. Need to write any join query?

Comment: what information you want? i 'll tell you

Comment: You have to make the join query from wp_posts, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships

Comment: can u help me.i dono how to write join query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :-

14 is the category id

```
 $request = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts 
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)  
  LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)  

  WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id <> 14  
     AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'   
     AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'  
     AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
     AND post_title like '%$search%'
     AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d').")");
```

Comment: you can replace $wpdb from wp_

Comment: Getting syntax error.all my table name starts <b>work_</b> instead of <b>wp_.</b>.can u help me

Comment: then, add work_. It was just an example. wp_ is common, so I used that :)

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM work_posts 
  LEFT JOIN work_term_relationships ON(work_posts.ID = work_term_relationships.object_id)  
  LEFT JOIN work_term_taxonomy ON(work_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = work_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)  

  WHERE (work_term_taxonomy.term_id <> 14  
     AND work_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'   
     AND work_posts.post_type = 'post'  
     AND work_posts.post_status = 'publish')'

Comment: u r really gr8. it's works. pls keep in touch with me.

Comment: Sure, I will. Please except both the answers :)

Comment: Hi, In this query, I want to get today date post only.how to edit? pls help

Comment: add AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'"

Comment: Showing error...`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Y-m-d') . &quot;'&quot;`

Comment: I tried this `AND post_date >= CURRENT_DATE`..it's works

Comment: Hi, this is my site webservice, it's working good. but one issue is here on "post_count". I used two types of query 1) date wise 2) normal . In normal search, result show all the posts of category. In date wise search, result show particular date posts. so post_count should be differnt. how can i display the post_count of these results.any hep?
 
 Chk this link. i have uploaded my file. http://www.filedropper.com/postcount

Comment: you can use $count = mysql_num_rows($sql_res)

Comment: Now, please except my both answers now. :P

Comment: Means, what should i do? i can't understand.

Comment: Hi, i want to create one page wordpress scrolling site like this  http://themes.opendept.net/retro-portfolio-4/ any idea?

Comment: you will get wordpress theme like this

Comment: http://www.mageewp.com/demo/?theme=onetone

    http://demo.enginethemes.com/oneengine/

Comment: Hi, i want to show my aboutus page content in my home page(index.php).i use this query.  `     $pages = get_pages();</br> 
     foreach ($pages as $page_data) {</br>
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); </br>
     $title = $page_data->post_title; </br>
     echo "<h1 class=\"entry-title1\">".$title."</h1>"</br>
     ."<div class=\"entry-content\">".$content."</div>";</br>
     }
     ?>`it shows all page content. i want particular page.can u help me?

Comment: Use get_post() instead of get_pages()

Comment: Is is possible to use jquery datepicker for fetching data from db on selecting particular date ?

Comment: I'm using the JQuery DatePicker, it's working. now i want to get particular posts date wise. how can i connect datepicker with mysql query

Comment: chk this page  http://dev.clonet.in/seyassah/category/social/  date picker jquery is working

Comment: i got code from this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: you can use filter_where

Comment: check this :- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97459/add-filter-and-remove-filter-added-before-and-after-wp-query

Comment: how to connect datepicker date to mysql date...did u chk my link..dev.clonet.in/seyassah/category/social..in this page, click text box, calender will open.if i click aug 15, aug 15 th posts should be display..now current date posts are displaying

Comment: `<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
               $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()
       });
   </script>


    Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"/>`

Comment: check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709817/process-mysql-function-and-display-using-jquery-ajax-with-time-invterval-for-ea/24709852#24709852

Comment: I have given answer to use ajax

Comment: Sorry for asking, what is url:, type:, data:. i dono anything in ajax. pls help me..see my above datepicker code.this is file of query page. how to connect.  http://www.filedropper.com/category

Comment: do you have sky pe? I can help you after my office hours i.e; after 7 pm IST. I am in office rite now

Comment: thanks. gunabalan22. this is my skype id.am also in office. i ll reach home at 7.45 pm.

Comment: will u come online now?

Comment: hi, i tried this code. please check is it correct or not. b'coz it's not retrive anything..current date posts and datepicker date also not working..this is my code..http://www.filedropper.com/catey

Comment: Please check this link and help me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521014/jquery-datepicker-with-ajax-is-not-working

Comment: hi chk this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795769/drupal-how-to-add-html-conent-into-page-tpl-php