# How to get all posts from one category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to get all posts from one category. i tried this code , it's not showing any output.Is it correct or any correction is here?  Thanks.

```
  include('wp-config.php');


  global $wp_query;

 $args = ('category=news&posts_per_page=-1');

 $myposts = get_posts( $args );


 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
   $result =  array(
   "id"=>$args['ID'],
   "type"=>$args['post_type'],
   "url"=>$args['guid']);
 endforeach; 

wp_reset_postdata();
print($result);
```

Comment: Where are you running this code and why do you call `global $wp_query`. Why not make use of the [`WP_POST` Member Variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).

Comment: Am just create one php file and testing. i want to display post from one category, but in array. can you help me.

Comment: What do you mean "in array"

Comment: `$result =  array(
   "id"=>$args['ID'],
   "type"=>$args['post_type'],
   "url"=>$args['guid']);`    Result should be inside array

Answer (score 2):

Try below :-

```
    global $wp_query;

 $args = ('category=news&posts_per_page=-1');

 $myposts = get_posts( $args );


 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 

   $result[] =  array(
   "id"=>$post->ID, // changed $args to $post
   "type"=>$post->post_type,
   "url"=>$post->guid);
 endforeach; 

wp_reset_postdata();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It's not showing anything. did u chk in your local?

Comment: please check now. I have made changes

Comment: One more help. did u chk my another question about mysql? if u knw the answer pls help me

Comment: where is the another question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931531/get-posts-from-all-categories-except-one-category?noredirect=1#comment38777535_24931531

Comment: Hi, the result shows only one post.other posts are not showing

Comment: `global $wp_query;

     $args = ('category=news&posts_per_page=-1');

     $myposts = get_posts( $args );


     foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 

     $result[] =  array(
     "id"=>$post->ID, // changed $args to $post
     "type"=>$post->post_type,
     "url"=>$post->guid,
     "status"=>$post->post_status,   
     "post_count"=>COUNT(id));
     endforeach; 

     wp_reset_postdata();
     print_r($result);`

Comment: i tried this code for find the post count.                           `"post_count"=>COUNT(id)`

Comment: it shows post count is 1. but total no of post is 10.

Comment: try count($result[0]), after endforeach

Comment: can u tell ur official mail id.i 'll send my code.i can't post here.

Comment: after foreach, then how i can use count inside loop?

Comment: why you want count inside foreach() ?

Comment: Am writing web services. so i have to show "post_count" inside array...if i try "count($result[0])" after foreach , then how can i use inside array.

Comment: How do i get these class details using jquery?    `text =$(this).find('.image_name').text();`

Comment: `$("#imgClick").live('click',function(){ var x=[];  u=0;
$("input:checkbox[name=imageselect]:checked").each(function()
{u++;
var lab=$(this).attr('id');
var m=$("#"+lab).html();
x.push(m);
});
 var sample='';
if(u==0){
alert("no item selected");
$("#printorder").hide();
$("#printorderArab").hide();
$("#customerPhotos").show();
} 
sample+='<div class="selected_image left ">'+x[i]+'</div>`
The process is, i can select images from products page and then purchase.in products page, images are showing, when i go to purchase page image is not showing. they used +x[i]+ code for images.

Comment: I think you should ask these questions in another new post. so that any other person can also reply :)

Comment: yeah i knw..but i need but ur help

Comment: shall i send the link of my website

Comment: select images & click "choose size & quantity" button,images are not showing."undefined"

Comment: I cannot see "choose size & quantity" button. Please send me the link for the product page

Comment: u have to login, then only u can see that page.how i send in public

Comment: Hi leave all above things. How to get commented post from all categories  . I tried this code, `$sql_qry="SELECT *
FROM news_posts, news_comments
WHERE ID = '$Commentpostid'
AND ID = comment_ID
GROUP BY ID";`sometime it works, fewtimes not working. can u help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052874/do-i-have-to-approve-post-comments-in-wordpress

Comment: chk this link & help me

Answer (score 1):

are you just trying to get posts from a category?

This is a handy code from the Codex that I keep around. Use this on any custom category page or anywhere on any page, for that matter, to start the loop. Make sure you put your category slug into the right spot in the code.

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'my-category-slug', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
// YOUR STUFF LIKE the_title(); or the_content();
endwhile; endif;
```

This is NOT a fix to your code, but it answers the question you asked. I think your problem may be in the use of $args inside the loop (seems odd), but if you want me to make sure I might need more of the code or a working example I can see.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category

**AHEM...yeah... I'm an idiot... don't go pasting this around. Use `WP_Query`!! thanks Pieter.**

Comment: yes. it's works. but i want to show result in array.                                                                                            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
    $result =  array(
   "id"=>$args['ID'],
   "type"=>$args['post_type'],
   "url"=>$args['guid']);
 endforeach;                                                     this section is correct or not? [ID, post_type, guid's are column name of WP_posts].is it possible to show like this?

Comment: I might be confused... what unique information are you trying to store in the array? You are calling $args, which is ('category=news&posts_per_page=-1'), and not any kind of loop command that might store a variable you want... such as getting the ID (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID), getting the post type (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type), or the link (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink). I think $args might be throwing an error with its odd formatting in the array? I am not a PHP expert.

Comment: `query_posts` should **NEVER** be used. If you need a custom query, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`. If you need to alter the main query, use `pre_get_posts`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display posts from a specific category in the category page, you can use the below given code in your theme's category.php file.

```
<?php
    if(have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            <?php
                the_post_thumbnail();
                the_content();    
            ?>
<?php
        endwhile;        
    endif;
?>
```

If you want to display the same in pages other than category page, just add the following code to the corresponding files.

```
<?php
    $posts = new WP_Query();
    $posts->query( "category_name='{enter your category slug here}'&posts_per_page=-1" );
    if($posts->have_posts()) :
        while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();
?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            <?php
                the_post_thumbnail();
                the_content();    
            ?>
<?php
        endwhile;        
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your theme directory, search **category.php**. If it doesn't contain, create a new file category.php and paste this code:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php endwhile; else :?>
<?php endif;?>
```