# Approve all wp post comments before publish?

Tags: wordpress

I have to approve all my post comments before publish. any one can help me?

Comment: you dont want to approve your comments before publish ?

Comment: I want to approve comments before publish

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings -> Discussion and then deselect appropriate checkboxes (like "Comment must be manualy approved"). Some more info about those settings you can find here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_Screen

Comment: i did select & deselect option same like this link(http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_Screen).still command is showing without approve. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
Dashboard - Settings - discussions

Before a comment appears:

Comment must be manually approved 
Comment author must have a previously approved comment
Uncheck both.
```

Comment: Need to change anything in coding?

Comment: Do you really want this way only? As this for security purpose

Comment: Yes for security purpose only. b'coz maybe someone comment badly, tats y.

Comment: yes, thats why they have given approval facility. Why you want to remove then ?

Comment: Then, check "Comment must be manually approved " Dashboard - Settings - discussions

Comment: i check "Comment must be manually approved " option, still it's nt waiting for approval. it's showing only