# Jquery datepicker with Ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

In my website there are many categories. Each category page have their posts. Here I used jQuery datepicker, if user want to see Aug 20th posts, they click particular date on calender & see the date posts. One more thing, if I open one category the posts of today should be displayed only. Please check this code and help me. This code displays all posts of category & datepicker is not retrieving anything.

This is mysql query in function.php

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
 {
 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  '%m/%d/%Y' AND post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");
 $pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res);

 exit();
 }  
 ?>
```

This is my script & PHP code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 <!--current date posts-->
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var day = currentTime.getDate();
     var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
     var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

    if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
    }

    if (month < 10) {
            month = "0" + month;
    }

    var today_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    var dataString ='date='+today_date;

 $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?datepost",
          data: dataString,

          success: function(data) {
              $('#testdiv').html(data);
          }
            });     <!--End current date posts-->


 <!--select date posts-->
    $("#datepicker").datepicker ({
            onSelect: function(dateTypeVar, inst) {
                    var dateAsObject =   $(this).val();
                    var dataString ='date='+dateAsObject;
                    $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?datepost",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(data) {

              $('#testdiv').html(data);
          }
            });  <!--End select date posts-->
    }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

PHP coding:

```
 Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"/>
  <?php while (have_posts()) :the_post();

 ?>
     <div id="testdiv"> 
  <div class="featuredpost">


 <div class="cat-block">
         <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-catpage' ) ?></a>

         <h2 class="posttitle"> <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark" title="" ><?php echo $key_1_values = get_post_meta($postid, '_visual-subtitle', true ); ?></a>
         </h2>

              <p> <?php $content = get_the_excerpt();
                                   $contentrecord=htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(stripslashes($content)));
                           echo substr($contentrecord, 0, 350); ?></p>
          <p class="postmeta"><span class="meta_date"><?php the_time('Y/m/d g:i:s A'); ?>
          <input id="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postid; ?>" name="post__id">
          <p>

          </span><span class="meta_permalink"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" title="111" rel="bookmark">التفاصيل</a>     </span>     </p>

 </div>


 </div>
 </div>  


 <?php endwhile;
 wp_reset_query();?>
 </div>
```

Comment: where is the html element with the id 'datepicker' ?

Comment: sorry i didn't write that. am new to ajax. can you explain me what is the mistake i made

Comment: use console and paste error you are getting?

Comment: i didn't get any error.now it's ahowing all posts of category...

Comment: This is my category page link: dev.clonet.in/seyassah/category/international/

Comment: Hi friends, any help..

Comment: Sorry coder, i was wrongly got ur point..this is my error in console.    
     ReferenceError: start is not defined
     ... PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm...
     "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dev.clonet.in/seyassah/wp-content/themes/syeh/css/blue/bg-body.png"
     TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function
     auto: 5000
     Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
     TypeError: e.init is not a function
     ... g(){using("tfw/hub/client",function(e){twttr.events.hub=e.init(p),e.init(p,!0)}...

Comment: Anybody is here to help me..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
 {
 $date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($_POST['date']));

 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  $date AND post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");
 $pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res);

 exit();
 }  
?>
```

Provide actual value for post_date column like  DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  $date