# How to display post featured images on category page?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi this is my query for display post details on category page. i displayed post tile & post content. i don't know how to display post image.. any one can help?

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
 {
 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  '".$date."' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status='publish'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");


 while($pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 echo $pageposts['post_title'];
 echo "\n<br />";
 echo $pageposts['post_content'];
 echo "\n<br />";

 }

 exit();
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somting like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
 {
 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  '".$date."' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status='publish'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");


 while($pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 echo $pageposts['post_title'];
 echo "\n<br />";
 echo $pageposts['post_content'];
 echo "\n<br />";
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageposts['ID'], 'thumbnail' ); 
 }

 exit();
 }
 ?>
```

or if you want src of the image you can use

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $pageposts['ID'] ), 'thumbnail' );
```

[REFER get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

You can do this a better way like this using Wordpress Loop

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        $post=the_post(); 
        the_title(); 
        echo "\n<br />";
        the_content();
        get_the_post_thumbnail();

    } 
}
?>
```

[WordPress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Great thanks man..it works.one more help. i used this query inside function.php, i want to give structure to my post details.so i need to use div structure. Is it possible to use <div class=""></div> inside function.php?

Comment: ya you can use , i feel even the above code can be written in a better way using WordPress functions

Comment: oh sorry. i don't have experience in wordpress function. can you help me?

Comment: check my updated code , if my answer worked for you please mark it  :)
do this in a seperate templated file[http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates], functions.php should be only used for writing function

Comment: How to write post details inside div. Am using this query. i want like this posts structure   http://al-seyassah.com/category/sports/. any help

Comment: `<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
     {
     $date = $_POST['date'];

     $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  '".$date."' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status='publish'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");


     while($pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {
     echo $pageposts['post_title'];
     echo "\n<br />";
     echo $pageposts['post_content'];
     echo "\n<br />";
     echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageposts['ID'], 'thumbnail' ); 
     }

     exit();
     }
    ?>`

Comment: <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        $post=the_post(); 
        the_title(); 
        echo "\n<br />";
        the_content();
        get_the_post_thumbnail();

    } 
}
?>

did you try this ? how is it outputing ?

Comment: Instead of this?  while($pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
 echo $pageposts['post_title'];
 echo "\n<br />";
 echo $pageposts['post_content'];
 echo "\n<br />";
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageposts['ID'], 'thumbnail' ); 
 }

Comment: Is it correct?   if(isset($_REQUEST['datepost']))
 {
 $date = $_POST['date'];

 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_date,  '%m/%d/%Y' ) =  '".$date."' AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status='publish'  ORDER BY post_date DESC");


 $pageposts=mysql_fetch_array($res);
if($pageposts!="") {
      if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) 
      { 
          $post=the_post(); 
          the_title(); echo "\n<br />"; 
          the_content(); 
          get_the_post_thumbnail(); } } 
  }
else{
    echo "No records";
}
 exit();
 }

Comment: actually its the whole code,replace the entire code with this,

Comment: then where i write mysql query

Comment: u dont need to write sql query wordpress loops finds post in decresing order of the date and my code does the same as urs

Comment: it's return empty value..am using datepicker with this.this is my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521014/jquery-datepicker-with-ajax-is-not-working/25521604#25521604